# Writing a csv and then checking values in columns and writing additional data

Tags: python, list, csv

so far I have written a long list (~45000 lines) of ID numbers along with additional reference values to a csv file. The data is structured as follows:

```
12345678 | 2
56789012 | 10
90123456 | 46
...
```

The code I've written so far to do this looks like this:

```
def list_writer():
    with open (csv_dir + '/' + csv_filename, mode = "w", newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, lineterminator='\n', delimiter=';')
        for row in ID_list:
            writer.writerow(row)

list_writer()
```

Every ID number (left column) is associated with a reference number (right column) which ranges from 1-100. I have several additional lists which associate every reference number with additional information (price, quantity, etc.).

My goal now is to loop through all the reference numbers in the second column of the long csv file I wrote, and write the additional properties to the next column. I've done some digging on StackExchange but nothing has worked so far. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The lists which associate each of the 100 reference numbers with the other properties I mentioned are already stored as lists in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this sounds like something I'd do in a relational (i.e. SQL) database, there are lots of tools there for validating your data and making sure it all stays consistant

if you want to do this in Python, you'd do something like:

```
# put your "lists of prices" into a dictionary, keyed by the reference number
# assuming the prices is in the form [(ref1, price1), (ref2, price2)]
ref_prices = {}
for ref, price in PRICE_list:
  ref_prices[ref] = price

# do the same for each additional list:
# shorter syntax than the above
ref_quantity = {ref: qty for ref, qty in QTY_list}

# combine all of the above and write into a file
with open(filename, 'w') as fd:
  out = csv.writer(fd, delimiter=';')
  for id, ref in ID_list:
    out.writerow((id, ref, ref_prices[ref], ref_quantity[ref]))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect use case for SQL. If you want to implement SQL-like functions in Python, it is often a good idea to use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html). It is convenient, easy to write and read, and quick. For your case, assuming that the additional values would be stored in a list of tuples or in a dictionary:

```
import pandas as pd


csv = [
    (1, 10),
    (2, 20),
    (3, 30),
]

csv_df = pd.DataFrame(csv, columns=["id", "reference"])

# This would be the data you have in your csv. For actually loading them from your 
# csv located at `filepath`, use 
#
#      pd.DataFrame.read_csv(filepath)

additional_data = [
    (1, "a"),
    (2, "b"),
    (3, "c"),
]  # This could also be a dictionary

additional_df = pd.DataFrame(additional_data, columns=["id", "name"])

final_df = csv_df.merge(additional_df, on="id")
```

Then we get

```
>>> final_df
   id  reference name
0   1         10    a
1   2         20    b
2   3         30    c
```

Comment: Thank you for your response - unfortunately I am using Python within ANSA and the pandas module is not available here, so I need to do this in Python.

Comment: @najusten If you want to use pandas, you have to install it before. I don't work with ANSA, but this post suggests you can install third external packages there as well: http://www.qd-eng.de/index.php/2018/03/02/third-party-python-modules-for-ansa/